# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified OR They don't get passed at all

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am trying to figure out why my update command isn't working. It seems to have something with the DataKeys field on GridView. (That's how I got the delete function to work without specifying delete Parameters as they coincide with the stored procedure to delete from the gridview and sql datasource.) However my grid view update function needs way more parameters. So I pass all the values and I get the titular error. If I remove all the parameters in the update section of the gridview, and pass in code behind it says the values weren't passed at all.

I just don't seem to understand how to add the parameters to this. I have tried `SqlDataSource2.DeleteParameters.Add("@Product", product);` or using a sql statement in code behind, but they don't seem to work. Can someone help me?

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestAdamConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TestRedo]"
        DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" DeleteCommand="deleteFromGrid" OnUpdating="SqlDataSource2_Updating" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="updateValues">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name ="@Product" />
            <asp:Parameter Name ="@Type" />
            <asp:Parameter Name ="@2016AccCode" />
            <asp:Parameter Name ="@2017BudgetAccCode" />
            <asp:Parameter Name ="@BusinessUnit" />
            <asp:Parameter Name ="@Group" />
            <asp:Parameter Name ="@TIAYTD" />
            <asp:Parameter Name ="@InvoiceDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name ="@RenewPeriod" />
            <asp:Parameter Name ="@AdvancedCancel" />
            <asp:Parameter Name ="@Renew" />
            <asp:Parameter Name ="@Notes" />
            <asp:Parameter Name ="@DueSoon" />
            <asp:Parameter Name ="@jOrS" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateValues] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Vendor nvarchar(max),
@Product nvarchar(max),
@Type nvarchar(max),
@2016AccCode nvarchar(max),
@2017BudgetAccCode nvarchar(max),
@BusinessUnit nvarchar(max),
@Group nvarchar(max),
@TIAYTD nvarchar(max),
@InvoiceDate nvarchar(max),
@RenewPeriod nvarchar(max),
@Expiration datetime,
@AdvancedCancel nvarchar(max),
@ActionReq datetime,
@Renew nvarchar(max),
@Notes nvarchar(max),
@DueSoon nvarchar(max),
@jOrS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
UPDATE TestRedo 
SET [Product/Service] = @Product,
[Type] = @Type,
[2016AccCode] = @2016AccCode,
[2017BudgetAccCode] = @2017BudgetAccCode,
BusinessUnit = @BusinessUnit,
[Group] = @Group,
TIAYTD = @TIAYTD,
InvoiceDate = @InvoiceDate,
RenewPeriod = @RenewPeriod,
AdvancedCancel = @AdvancedCancel,
Renew = @Renew,
Notes = @Notes,
DueSoon = @DueSoon,
[John/Steve] = @jOrS

WHERE Vendor = @Vendor AND Expiration = @Expiration AND ActionReq = @ActionReq
END

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ActionReq, Vendor, Expiration" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                    Width="95%" AllowSorting="True" AllowCustomPaging="False" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ForeColor="Black" 
                    GridLines="Horizontal" HeaderStyle-CssClass="pagination" SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="NotSet" CellPadding="5" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" RowStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" 
                    OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" SelectedRowStyle-HorizontalAlign="NotSet" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
                    OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">

                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateBtn" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit"/>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"/>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"/>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteBtn" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"
                                    OnClientClick="return isDelete();">Delete
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You have Vendor as a parameter in the procedure but it is NOT part of the the UpdateParameters in your datasource. Do you really need nvarchar(max) here? Are you familiar with datatypes in sql server? Everything should NOT be nvarchar(max).

Comment: The reason they are that way is because of the nature of the information I am working with; this is a test table. Only 3 columns, Action, Vendor, and Expiration, have to be different - as I need the date functionality. I can fix datatypes later. Even with those columns in the update parameter field, it still says too many. I believe with DataKeys those values get automatically passed.

Comment: ASP.net will automatically add/send the DataKey (DataKeyNames="ActionReq, Vendor, Expiration") as parameters to your command.
You should probably write a handler function in code behind so you can control the parameters sent

Comment: Or You can modify your stored procedure to accept the additional parameters

Comment: How would that event handler start? I have GridView row updating and a sql data source updating. Which would I use?

Comment: I didn't see your question until now as you didn't address me (i.e.: @DaniDev)

 One way to do it is to use an asp:ObjectDataSource Control instead of asp:sqlDataSource. You then will have to write all your CRUD methods in that one Class this is where you can handle your parameters and calls to your stored procedures.